# query writing condition for powershell output with multiple ip

Tags: powershell

I have a variable, the example output shows as 10.10.102.83,True

example

```
$a = $ISCSI.InitiatorPortalAddress+ ',' +$ISCSI.IsConnected

1) echo $a = 10.10.102.83,True
2) echo $a = 0.0.0.0 10.30.28.31 ,True True
3) echo $a = 10.0.0.1 10.30.28.31 ,True True
```

I need to write a condition that. if $a output comes with more than one IP as mentioned in example 2 or example 3 ( the IP may be differ in each output) the script should fail.

Can anyone help me to write the condition here ?

Comment: You could test on `$ISCSI.Count` being `-gt 1`. Can you show how you assign the `$ISCSI` variable? You might get bitten by powershell creating an array of objects or assigning just one object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$ISCSI` variable contains more than one object.

You're not accessing `$ISCSI` one time when you call `.IsConnected` - you actually get the result of `.IsConnected` on every object in the array, which in this case is multiple `$true`s.

PowerShell's default behavior when printing arrays is to print them with a space between them, resulting in the output you see there.

You can just use something like this to ensure you only have one object before Proceeding.

```
if ($ISCSI.Count -gt 1){
    #Throw Error
} else {
    $a = $ISCSI.InitiatorPortalAddress+ ',' +$ISCSI.IsConnected
    #Other Logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$a = "0.0.0.0 10.30.28.31" ,"True True"
$count=(($a -split ',')[0] -split ' ').Count

if ($count -gt 1)
{
    throw 'No good!'
    exit
}

"test"
```

Comment: Yeah. This works well. Can you explain me what actually script does here